# In a computer why does adding one to the maximum integer results in zero?

Tags: binary

I wonder the process of addition in computers.

How do computers add two number? Is it an electronic magic? Is it an algorithm?

Also, I wonder why adding 1 to Max integer (...111) results in zero (...000)? Asuming ...111 is the binary representation of max int in that computer architecture.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't always result in 0. If you're using a signed integer type in the most representation, you'll end up with the *minimum* value, going from (say)

```
01111111 (127)
10000000 (-127)
```

On some architectures - and in some modes, at least - this sort of overflow doesn't give a value, it causes an error. When it *does* give a value, it's basically still just binary counting. Imagine you have an 8-bit unsigned integer value... the last few values would be

```
 11111100
 11111101
 11111110
 11111111
```

then the *logical* next step is to go into the next bit:

```
100000000
```

So the computer effectively does that - but then throws away that new top bit, keeping just the bottom 8 bits (because it's an 8-bit type).

You don't have to use computers to see this sort of effect though. Suppose you have an analogue odometer in a car - the kind with several "wheels". As you get to the end of its range, it just wraps round:

```
99997
99998
99999
00000 // Overflow!
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Eloquent, well explained and still simple to understand. Well done.

Comment: Jon Skeet's answer is just awesome, always

Comment: Is it safe to consider all modern architectures will not cause overflow and will just result in 0 in case of adding 1 to unsigned short with value 65,535 for example?

Comment: @doc_id: It depends on the language, and it's options. For example, in C# there's a concept of "checked" or "unchecked" contexts - in a checked context, and exception will be thrown; in an unchecked context it won't.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case in an arithmetic processor which implements two's complement binary arithmetic for integers. It is not true of, say, floating point numbers and it's not necessarily true on rare computers that do math in other ways (sign-magnitude representations, etc).

two's complement makes certain things easy for the hardware, like implementing some signed and unsigned operations using the same logic.

Remember, the value 1111...1111 represents -1 under two's complement, and you want -1 to increment to 0.

1111111..111 goes to zero "naturally". When you add 1, a carry of 1 propagates through the number, causing every digit to turn to 0, and then it carries out of the number (where it is discarded, or used to set an overflow indication).

Answer (score 0):

The process of addition is hardware related and done ALU in your CPU .
Adding 1 to Max integer will cause in zero
Because in binary system adding 1 to 1 will result in zero and 1 added to the next digit
So the adding 1 to 11111
1+1=0 and 1 shifted to the next digit and so on

Answer (score 0):

> How do computers add two number? Is it an electronic magic? Is it an algorithm?

Computers use an algorithm called **[2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)** to represent positive and negative numbers (signed numbers).

Following is the explanation of `Sign Bit`, `1's complement` and `2's complement`.

Let's take a `4 bit` integer

### Sign Bit

```
| Binary  | Decimal |
| :-----: | :-----: |
| 1 1 1 1 |   -7    |
| 1 1 1 0 |   -6    |
| 1 1 0 1 |   -5    |
| 1 1 0 0 |   -4    |
| 1 0 1 1 |   -3    |
| 1 0 1 0 |   -2    |
| 1 0 0 1 |   -1    |
| 1 0 0 0 |   -0    |
| 0 0 0 0 |   +0    |
| 0 0 0 1 |   +1    |
| 0 0 1 0 |   +2    |
| 0 0 1 1 |   +3    |
| 0 1 0 0 |   +4    |
| 0 1 0 1 |   +5    |
| 0 1 1 0 |   +6    |
| 0 1 1 1 |   +7    |
```

As you can see from the above truth table, the difference between +5 and -5 is just the left most bit, i.e., the **Most Significant Bit**.
The MSB is used to determine the sign of the number. Hence, the name.

There are a few problems with this approach,

1. There's a `+0` and a `-0`.
2. If you add 2 numbers. For e.g., `+5` and `-5` you should get `0` but when adding `0 1 0 1` with `1 1 0 1` you get `1 0 0 1 0`, we're using 4 bit integer, so we can ignore the first 1. So, we get `0 0 1 0` which is `2`.

So, to fix the issues, scientist devised 1's complement.

### 1's Complement

```
| Binary  | Decimal |
| :-----: | :-----: |
| 1 0 0 0 |   -7    |
| 1 0 0 1 |   -6    |
| 1 0 1 0 |   -5    |
| 1 0 1 1 |   -4    |
| 1 1 0 0 |   -3    |
| 1 1 0 1 |   -2    |
| 1 1 1 0 |   -1    |
| 1 1 1 1 |   -0    |
| 0 0 0 0 |   +0    |
| 0 0 0 1 |   +1    |
| 0 0 1 0 |   +2    |
| 0 0 1 1 |   +3    |
| 0 1 0 0 |   +4    |
| 0 1 0 1 |   +5    |
| 0 1 1 0 |   +6    |
| 0 1 1 1 |   +7    |
```

In this, everything from `+0` to `+7` is the same as before. The difference is with the negative numbers. We take the positive number's binary, and we complement all the bits. So, `0` becomes `1` and `1` becomes `0`.
You can see for e.g., `+5` and `-5`, the former is `0 1 0 1` and the latter is `1 0 1 0`.

So, now if we add `+5` and `-5` like before `0 1 0 1` and `1 0 1 0`, it gives `1 1 1 1` which is `-0`.

But here also, we have some issues,

1. There still is `+0` and `-0`.
2. Let's try adding `+5` and `-3` that's `0 1 0 1` and `1 1 0 0`, adding them we get, `1 0 0 0 1`. Again, ignoring the first 1, we get `0 0 0 1`
   and that's `+1` but it should be `+2`. Similarly, if we add `+6` and `-2` we should get `+4` but adding `0 1 1 0` and `1 1 0 1`, we get `1 0 0 1 1` i.e., `0 0 1 1` which is `+3`.

So, if we add `+1` to all the answers, the answers becomes correct. `0 0 1 1` + `1` is `0 1 0 0` which is `+4`.

### 2's Complement

This method is very similar to **1's complement**.

```
|  Binary  |   Decimal    |
| :------: | :----------: |
| -8 4 2 1 | place values |
| 1 0 0 0  |      -8      |
| 1 0 0 1  |      -7      |
| 1 0 1 0  |      -6      |
| 1 0 1 1  |      -5      |
| 1 1 0 0  |      -4      |
| 1 1 0 1  |      -3      |
| 1 1 1 0  |      -2      |
| 1 1 1 1  |      -1      |
| 0 0 0 0  |      +0      |
| 0 0 0 1  |      +1      |
| 0 0 1 0  |      +2      |
| 0 0 1 1  |      +3      |
| 0 1 0 0  |      +4      |
| 0 1 0 1  |      +5      |
| 0 1 1 0  |      +6      |
| 0 1 1 1  |      +7      |
```

What this method does is, it gets rid of the `-0` and therefore, we have `-8`. So, `0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1` i.e., `127` becomes `1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0` i.e., <s>127</s> `-128` because `0` to `127` is `128` and `-1` to `-128` is `128`. Hence, `2^8` = `256`.

And, if we add 2 numbers just like before `+5` and `-5` i.e., `0 1 0 1` and `1 0 1 1` we get `1 0 0 0 0` i.e., `0 0 0 0` which is exactly `0`. No weird `-0` and `+0`. Let's take another example i.e `+6` and `-2` i.e., `0 1 1 0` and `1 1 1 0`, we get `1 0 1 0 0` i.e., `0 1 0 0` which is `4`. *YAY!*.

But that's not all, 2's complement packs even more logic. In the above table you can see the **Least significant bit** i.e., the right most bit is `1` i.e., `2^0` and then `2` i.e., `2^1` and then `4` i.e., `2^2` but then `-8` i.e., `-2^3`. So, if we take `-5` as example, we get `1 0 1 1` i.e., `(1 * -2^3) + (0 * 2^2) + (1 * 2^1) + (1 * 2^0)` i.e., `-8 + 0 + 2 + 1` which is `-5`. ***Maths is the real magic here***.

Now, to negate the number `+5` for example. We have to do 2 steps, instead of 1 like the previous methods.

1. We have to take complement (invert) i.e., `0 1 0 1` becomes `1 0 1 0`.
2. Then, we have to add `1` i.e., `1 0 1 0` + `1` so, it becomes `1 0 1 1` which is `-5`.

This method works great, and we get an extra number to store. That's the reason a normal `int` (32 bit) in `C++` has a range of `2^31` to  `2^31 - 1`.

Comment: References:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement
https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zjfgjxs/revision/5
https://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/19068/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qH4unVtJkE